# Mule - Retry connection with basic flow

Tags: java, http, soap, exception, mule

I have a basic mule flow:

**HTTP** => **SOAP** => **JAVA CLASS**

```
<mule xmlns:cxf="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf" xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" version="EE-3.6.1"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/cxf/current/mule-cxf.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <flow name="test_dynamicsFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="CXF"/>
        <component doc:name="Java"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

I would like to make a **retrying connection** to SOAP with **timeout** but I don't know if it possible.

I've been looking for error **handling connectors**:

[image]

Should I use these connectors to do that or how can I implement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your HTTP call with the `until-successful` scope.

Example:

```
<until-successful objectStore-ref="objectStore" maxRetries="5" secondsBetweenRetries="60" >
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="submit" method="POST" />
</until-successful>
```

Reference: https://developer.mulesoft.com/docs/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope

Comment: With this solution can I return a message?

Comment: In synchronous mode: yes.

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, I have that option but I would like to return a personalized XML message. I need to make a new Java class? I think I need this too: `deadLetterQueue-ref`

Comment: Finally, I use `until-successful` scope with java component:   `<until-successful maxRetries="3"
   secondsBetweenRetries="60" doc:name="Until Successful" synchronous="true">
   <component doc:name="Java">
    <spring-object bean="testIntegration" />
   </component>
  </until-successful>` but it return an error: `Exception thrown inside until-successful org.mule.component.ComponentException: Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{Flow_test.component.1805940825}. Message payload is of type: String `

Comment: Please open a new question, comments are not the place for follow ups.

Comment: Sorry, I've already open a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30579795/mule-throw-exception-with-until-successful . Thank you for your help.