# Mule - Throw Exception with until-successful

Tags: java, soap, exception, mule

This is my mule flow:

**HTTP** => **Logger** => **SOAP (CXF)** => Until Successful [**JAVA**]  => **LOGGER**

Spring :

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <spring:property name="locations">
            <spring:list>
                <spring:value>test.properties</spring:value>
            </spring:list>
        </spring:property>
    </spring:bean>
    <spring:bean id="testIntegration"
        class="x.x.x.IntegrationClass" init-method="init">
        <spring:property name="url" value="${destiny.url}" />
        <spring:property name="username" value="${message.username}" />
        <spring:property name="password" value="${message.password}" />
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
```

Flow:

```
    <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response"
        host="localhost" port="8087" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

    <cxf:jaxws-service doc:name="Test service"
        serviceClass="dynamics.file.request.Requests" />

    <until-successful maxRetries="3"
        secondsBetweenRetries="60" doc:name="Until Successful" synchronous="true">
        <component doc:name="Java">
            <spring-object bean="testIntegration" />
        </component>
    </until-successful>
    <logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO"
        doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
```

The Java component returns a String (XML but String) and when I use `until-successful` it shows me this error:

```
Exception thrown inside until-successful org.mule.component.ComponentException: Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{Flow_test.component.1805940825}. Message payload is of type: String

[[test_flow].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: 

********************************************************************************
Message               : Failed to find entry point for component, the following resolvers tried but failed: [
MethodHeaderPropertyEntryPointResolver: The required property "method" is not set on the event
CallableEntryPointResolver: Object "es.test.integration.testIntegration@4eb6b10c" does not implement required interface "interface org.mule.api.lifecycle.Callable"
ReflectionEntryPointResolver: Found too many possible methods on object "es.test.integration.testIntegration" that accept parameters "{class java.lang.String}", Methods matched are "[public java.lang.String es.test.integration.testIntegration.cte(java.lang.String), public java.lang.String es.test.integration.testIntegration.cancelCte(java.lang.String), public java.lang.String es.test.integration.testIntegration.newCte(java.lang.String), public java.lang.String es.test.integration.testIntegration.totalCte(java.lang.String), public java.lang.String es.test.integration.testIntegration.resultCte(java.lang.String), public java.lang.String es.test.integration.testIntegration.newCte(java.lang.String), public java.lang.String es.test.integration.testIntegration.cteAll(java.lang.String)]"
AnnotatedEntryPointResolver: Component: es.test.integration.testIntegration@4eb6b10c doesn't have any annotated methods, skipping.
]
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-321

    at org.mule.model.resolvers.DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.invoke(DefaultEntryPointResolverSet.java:49)
    at org.mule.component.DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.invoke(DefaultComponentLifecycleAdapter.java:339)
    at org.mule.component.AbstractJavaComponent.invokeComponentInstance(AbstractJavaComponent.java:82)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

---

```
Message               : Software caused connection abort: socket write error (java.net.SocketException)
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Software caused connection abort: socket write error (java.net.SocketException)
  java.net.SocketOutputStream:-2 (null)
2. Software caused connection abort: socket write error (java.net.SocketException) (org.mule.api.DefaultMuleException)
  org.mule.transport.http.HttpMessageProcessTemplate:170 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/DefaultMuleException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************
```

With that error I suppose that I need any parameters here but correct me if I'm wrong:

```
public void init()
{

    NtlmAuthenticator authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator(username,password);
    Authenticator.setDefault(authenticator);

    Requestsservice = new Requests();
    clntprt = service.getSolicitudesPort();

    Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(cliente);
    HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();

    HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
    httpClientPolicy.setAllowChunking(false);

    http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

    BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) clntprt;
    provider.getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                    url);
}
```

**Updated:**

Where I have the init method I have the implemented methods (These both for example, but there are more):

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "CancelCte", action = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests:CancelCte")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "CancelCte", targetNamespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests", className = "x.x.Requests.CancelCte")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "CancelCte_Result", targetNamespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests", className = "x.x.Requests.CancelCteResult")
@WebResult(name = "return_value", targetNamespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests")
public String CancelCte(
        @WebParam(name = "xmlInput", targetNamespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests") String xmlInput) 
{
    return client.CancelCte(xmlInput);
}

@WebMethod(operationName = "newCte", action = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests:newCte")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "newCte", targetNamespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests", className = "x.x.Requests.newCte")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "newCte_Result", targetNamespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests", className = "x.x.Requests.newCteResult")
@WebResult(name = "return_value", targetNamespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests")
public String newCte(
        @WebParam(name = "xmlInput", targetNamespace = "urn:microsoft-dynamics-schemas/codeunit/Requests") String xmlInput) 
{
    return client.newCte(xmlInput);
}
```

Like now, automatically use the necessary method.

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace? Also why using a custom transformer: isn't the 'xml-to-dom-transformer` that comes bundled with Mule enough for your needs?

Comment: What do you mean when you say stacktrace?. No, I don't use the transformer, is only an idea to avoid the exception. What do you recommend?

Comment: Below `Exception thrown inside until-successful` there must be a long message that shows the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the partial information you have provided, all I can say is that the source of the problem is located in:

```
<spring-object bean="testIntegration" />
```

based on: `Component that caused exception is: DefaultJavaComponent{Flow_test.component.1805940825}`

The main issue is that Mule can't locate a method to call on your custom component: there are two many methods of arity 1 that take `String`, which prevent Mule to pick an appropriate "entry point". Two solutions to fix this:

- Set a property named `method` with the method name to call as its value before the call to the component,
- Use the `invoke` message processor to call the desired method directly.

As a side note, it seems this component performs outbound HTTP calls: typically you want to use Mule HTTP to do this instead of doing it in custom code. First you're burying these interactions inside custom code: someone looking at the Mule config won't know that outbound HTTP call are involved. Moreover, Mule itself will not know so it can't do anything like general lifecycle and error management, stats... on these custom HTTP calls.

Comment: I have updated the post with long message and Java code that I use to connect.

Comment: I don't understand so much your solution, I added the spring beans to the post  if it gives you support.

Comment: OK, what method do you want Mule to invoke on the bean? There are so many methods that match (`cteAll`, `newCte`...): which one do you want to call?

Comment: I want to invoke testIntegration

Comment: There are no method named `testIntegration` that takes one String arg in the `testIntegration` bean. The methods that could be called are: `cte`, `cancelCte`, `newCte`, `totalCte`, `resultCte`, `newCte` and `cteAll`. Which one do you want to call?

Comment: OK, it depends on the label of the XML that I send. But for example, `newCte`

Comment: Cool, in this case add `<set-property propertyName="method" value="newCte"/>` before the `<component>`.

Comment: Sorry for making many questions, I'm learning with Mule (I'm reading your book Mule in Action too!). Now I have this: `<set-property propertyName="method" value="newCte" doc:name="Property"/>` and then: `<invoke object-ref="" method="method" doc:name="Invoke"/>` and that before the `<component>`. What is the value for object ref?

Comment: The object ref will be the beanName in this case testIntegration?

Comment: If you use `invoke` you can remove both the `set-property` and `component` elements. It's one or the two others.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to use `invoke`. The object ref will be the same like the `component` object (in this `case core:spring-object bean=testIntegration`) and the method will be the name of the method that I use (in this case `init`). Correct me if I'm wrong please.

Comment: `init` is called by Spring during the initialization phase, it's not the method to which you want to route messages to. Since the message payload is a single `String`, it has to be one of these `cte` methods.

Comment: Really? But it is statically. It depends on the XML that I get. Can you give me a full example of the Invoke component? I added more info (methods that return the string) for your info. Thanks

Comment: Now, I have the `invoke component` with the objectRef `testIntegration` (bean name), method `newCte` (to test it) and method arguments: `#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]` but the XML that I get is `Failed to invoke x.x.x.integration.testIntegracion@4100da55. Message payload is of type: String`  Thanks

Comment: Open a new question with the full stacktrace you get in Mule's log.

Comment: OK. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30646989/mule-deployed-project-message-payload-is-of-type-string